# How can I limit available searchable options for Ransack gem based on attribute in advanced mode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I'm using the Ransack gem to create a search form for my users.  I've chosen to use the "Advanced" options they mention in their documentation ([here](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#advanced-mode)), and the page lists one set of drop-down-lists for attribute, predicate (<, >, ==, etc.), and a text box for specifying a value.  Then the user can add more conditions as they see fit.  My question is, how can I set the value boxes based on what attribute the user selected?

For instance, if they choose to search on the `age` attribute for the model I want to give them a drop-down-list of 0 to 125 or something similar.

I planned on using jquery to determine what value the user selected and then modify the value box depending on what was selected, but I'm not sure how to identify the form selection box to do so.  It contains a randomly generated value such as... `<select class="form-control" name="q[c][1450731292853][a][0][name]" id="q_c_1450731292853_a_0_name">`

**Edit:** Forgot here is my link that adds a new set of conditions to search by...

```
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, type)
    new_object = f.object.send "build_#{type}"
    id = "new_#{type}"
    fields = f.send("#{type}_fields", new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(type.to_s + "_fields", f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my issue by doing the following.  If you are using ransack this code should adapt very well "out-of-the-box".  My apologies, if you don't use *coffeescript*.

```
attributes_for_true_false_select = [
  'married'
  'dog owner'
]

attributes_for_only_string = [
  'first name'
  'last name'
]

jQuery ->
  $('select[name$="[name]"]').on 'change', ->
  name_string = $(this).attr 'id'
  selected_value = $("option:selected", this).text().toLowerCase()
  value_id = $(this).attr('id').replace('name', 'value')
  value_id = value_id.replace('a','v')

  # if the selected value is for true/false control then...
  if attributes_for_true_false_select.indexOf(selected_value) > -1

  # Find the value box and change to a drop down for true/false
  true_false_drop_down_list = '<select class="form-control" name="' + $('input[id=\''+value_id+'\']').attr('name') + '" id="' + ' $('input[id=\''+value_id+'\']').attr('id') + '"><option value="1">True</option><option value="0">False</option></select>'
  $('#'+value_id).replaceWith(true_false_drop_down_list)

  # if the selected value is for string control then...
  else if attributes_for_only_string.indexOf(selected_value) > -1

  # Find the value box and change to a text input box
  text_box_control = '<input class="form-control" type="text" name="' + $('input[id=\''+value_id+'\']').attr('name') + '" id="' + $('input[id=\''+value_id+'\']').attr('id') + '">'
  $('#' + value_id).replaceWith(text_box_control)

 return
```